# Cron Logic (Lua)

Tags: algorithm, lua, cron, cron-task

Im developing a Unix like Cron in Lua Jit, and im having a little troubles with the algorithm, maybe i dont think so well the logic order of execute or something like that, im trying to get a little pseudocode for help a little bit with the code.

if i receive a get an

```
`'* * * * *'`
```

im gonna do the job every minute of every hour, if i get a

```
'20 2 2 1 5'
```

i need to process that, and do a response like in a date format or something like that, thats not the important thing

My problem its the logic steps for do all the process in the right way taking all the possible cases. Im not looking for an specific code, just something for open my mind and understand a little bit how it is the actual translation.

Answer (score 0):

first, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

you are looking for something like this:

find out current datetime

```
current_datetime = get_datetime()
-> {year=.., month=.., day=.., weekday=.., hour=.., min=.., sec=..}
```

find out setup

```
given_string = '20 2 2 1 5 user, command'
cron_config, user, command = parse_cron_config(given_string) -> some object, and cmd
```

then check:

```
-- skip for wrong day

if cron_config:weekday_specified() or cron_config:monthday_specified() then
    if cron_config:weekday_specified() and current_datetime.weekday ~= cron_config.weekday then 
        return  -- skip!
    elseif ...
    end
end

if cron_config:hour_specified() and current_datetime.hour ~= cron_config.hour then
    return
end

...

-- finally found that all checks are done and operation should be performed

perform_job(command)
```

Comment: .. but i think, executing cronconfigs from lua is not good idea :(

Comment: Yeap thats the algorithm for check if im im in the cron time or if the cron time its past, btw im using the time.lua script, that can perform operations like + - and returns a new date, its parsed from a C library. My problem and what i want, but i think its more complicated, its return the next schedule date after getting a cron string. But at the end i think that im gonna end just checking the current time and compare with my cron time.